# Use swipe gesture to move from one page to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, zurb-foundation, hammer.js

I am building an app in phonegap for windows surface pro 3 tablet using AngularJS and Foundations. A user should be able to swipe sideways to move from one page to another. I don't know how to approach this problem and i tried using various libraries like hammer.js, swipe.js but doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help ?

this is the code that i wrote in hammerjs and then called the "swipeleft" function on one of the html element. It works fine, but on each swipe i should go to next page, right now it goes to only one page.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('first');
var hammer    = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
var swipe     = new Hammer.Swipe();
hammer.add(swipe);
hammer.on('swipeleft', function(){
window.location = '#/food-truck';
});
```

Comment: why don't you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

you can easily implement this using hammer.js. I did the same for my hybrid android app made for a wordpress blog.

1. First add hammer and jquery files inside head section.
2. Make a hammer object

```js
    var mc = new Hammer(main);
```

here "main" is the DIV where you want to detect the gestures. change it according to your app.

3. Now you gotta add these code blocks for every gesture, just like this:

```js
    mc.on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
        //trigger when user swipe left
    });
```

similarly you can code for swipe right:

```js
mc.on("swiperight", function(ev) {
   //trigger when user swipe right
});
```

Now for switching between next/previous posts, you can do something close to this. You gotta tailor this according to your app:

```js
mc.on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
   var post_nav = jQuery('link[rel="next"]');
  
   if ( post_nav ) {
    jQuery(location).attr('href', post_nav.attr('href'));
   }
});
```

This worked for me. This is what my whole code looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var mc = new Hammer(main);

mc.on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
   var post_nav = jQuery('link[rel="next"]');
  
   if ( post_nav ) {
    jQuery(location).attr('href', post_nav.attr('href'));
   }
});

mc.on("swiperight", function(ev) {
   var post_nav = jQuery('link[rel="prev"]');
  
   if ( post_nav ) {
    jQuery(location).attr('href', post_nav.attr('href'));
   }
});

});
```

Cheerio!